# joomla as a push CMS like cascades CMS

Tags: wordpress, joomla

There are several features in [Cascade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascade_Server) that I want in Joomla or Wordpress.
Cascade publishes all the content and make pre-render html files. At the frontend whenever users looks for anything it quickly renders the pre-generated html files.

Secondly it has folder based structure i.e you can create the folders and pages inside it. Thus same structure is followed while publishing.

Let say I have created following folder structure in Cascades:

- Publications

  - Marketing

    - Budgets
    - 2016
    - page1
    - page2
    - subfolder-2016

      - subpage-2016-1
      - subpage-2016-2
    - 2015
    - 2014

If I publish the publications folder, it will generate the HTML files for all the pages and keep the same folder structure on FTP. Now let say my site is `cascadessite.com` then I will be able to browse all the folders and their respective pages. e.g

`cascadessite.com/Publications/Marketing/Budget/2016/page1.aspx` or `page1.php` depends on my web server.

I want to do the same thing with Joomla or Wordpress. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about wordpress but in Joomla this is possible as you can create a heirarchy of categories instead of folders. So your entire articles are stored in database but maintains a structure as you mentioned. To get the url you wish, you can use sef components of joomla http://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/sef. Also you can create your own router file for the contents. Another tedious way is to modify the .htaccess but I am sure you don't need to do that, the addons are more than sufficient. As wordpress has lots of users it may be possible with wordpress too. YOu can enquire in their forum.

Comment: Thanks Ray, How it could be publish like static html files with same folder structures. e.g same structure should be there on FTP like the one we had created via categories. Let say category will become a folder and page become a static html resource. Is there a way ? 

Many Thanks.